# pydantic Settings: TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Tags: python, prometheus, pydantic

I am facing an issue with `pydantic.BaseSettings` and `prometheus_client.Summary`.
The snippet below throws an Exception when trying to be executed:

```
from prometheus_client import Summary
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str = 'any_app_name'
    any_boolean: bool = False
    any_summary: Summary = Summary('my_summary','My Summary')

s = Settings()
```

Here comes the stacktrace:

```
  File "/Users/XXX/workspace/src/settings_summary.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Settings(BaseSettings):
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 252, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 309, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 271, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 344, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 368, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._set_default_and_type
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 280, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.get_default
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

When removing the `Summary` line code runs:

```
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str = 'any_app_name'
    any_boolean: bool = False

s = Settings()
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest for me was to use an [automatically excluded attribute](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes):

```
from typing import ClassVar
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    any_summary: ClassVar[Summary] = Summary('my_summary','My Summary')
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassVar is not the best practice since it will construct a static variable that will be shared among all instances.

Here is my recommended solution which is just a simple demonstration, and you could update your code similarly:

```py
import threading
from typing import Optional, Any
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str = ...
    family: str = ...

    lock: Optional[type(threading.Lock())] = Field(  # use Optional to annotate the type and use Field to initialize
        exclude=True,  # remember to set the exclude to True
        title="lock"
    )

    rlock: Any = Field(  # or use Any to annotate the type and use Field to initialize
        exclude=True,
        title="rlock"
    )

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)  # Pydantic init
        self.lock = threading.Lock()  # remember to initialize inside the __init__ function
        self.rlock = threading.RLock()

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True  # this flag must be set!



u = User(**{"name": "milad", "family": "vayani"})

print(u.json())
```